# Get Column name of specific row and matching column in Excel

Tags: excel

I like to get this thing to do:

Input: Subject number  , Mark,
Output : Grade letter (column name)

Here is the sample excel table:

[image]

I have found the row number by using this function:

```
=MATCH(C7,A2:A4,0)
```

Now, how to find the value in that row and get output the column name ?

Comment: Have you tried the INDEX() function?

Comment: index function would return the given column value, but i want to find the column with matching value and then get the column name containing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change grade range to be increasing from Fail -> A you can use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(B1:H1,1,MATCH(C8,OFFSET(A2,MATCH(C7,A2:A4,0)-1,1,1,7),1))
```

(For clarity, the columns would be Fail, D, C-, C, B-, B+, A with the corresponding marks below it)
[image: Grade Table]

**EDIT**

After further thought, without changing the table, and avoiding the OFFSET function, the following should work:

```
=INDEX(B1:H1,COUNTIF(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C7,A:A)):INDEX(H:H,MATCH(C7,A:A)),">"&C8)+1)
```

Comment: This is the solution for ascending order. This works fine. But i was looking for a solution for descending order. I have tried using -1 in the above formula but it gives result of column next to then correct column, for example: if i put 9, it shows column d when using descending order.